# console log is not showing on the website. how can i display the consoled contents?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, grid

I can see the console.log on the console when i right click and inspect but i don't see on the website. I am basically clicking on a row in 1st grid and showing its contents in 2nd grid.

But, when I use

```
 const clickedContentArray = Array.isArray(clickedContent)
    ? clickedContent
    : [clickedContent];
```

and

```
data={clickedContentArray}
```

I see the contents of that row in the 2nd grid but as an array with its indexes. i want to display as a readable text such that it is scrollable downwards. Currently, with the array it is scrollable sideways which is not desired as it is a long array.

below is the code where i see in console and not on the website.
Please can anyone guide me. Thank you.

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    const rowIndex = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-row-index");
    const clickedContent = pimerror[rowIndex].content;
    setClickedContent(clickedContent);
    console.log(clickedContent);
  };

 const clickedContentArray = Array.toString(clickedContent)
    ? clickedContent
    : [clickedContent];
```

```
  <Grid item xs={12} lg={3.7}>
          <AdvancedTableView
            title="Test Files"
            id_sort="datetime"
            data={pimerror.map((error) => {
              // console.log(error);
              return {
                ...error,
                datetime: moment(error.datetime, "YYYYMMDDHHmmss").format(
                  " DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm:ss"
                ),
              };
            })}
           
            filter_list={["content"]}
            onRowClick={handleClick}
          />
        </Grid>

  <Grid item xs={12} lg={6} style={{ height: "550px", width: "100px" }}>
          {/* <Grid item xs={12} lg={6} style={{ height: "550px" }}> */}
          <AdvancedTableView
            title="Clicked Content"
           
            data={{ content: clickedContentArray }} // pass clickedContent to data prop
            filter_list={[]}
          />
        </Grid>
```